# Unpublish app on itunes is not reflecting

Tags: ios, iphone

Select your app in iTunes Connect.
Go to Pricing and Availability in the App Store and Information section.
Click Remove from Sale under Availability.
Click Save.

I followed this process.but after this, I can find my app on app store and I can download also.how much to take this to reflecting.

Answer (score 1):

From [Viewing and Changing Your App's status and Availability - iTunes Connect Developer's Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW17)

> Click Save - The status changes to Developer Removed From Sale. Within 24 hours,
>   your app won’t be seen on the store.

As stated above, it takes 24 hours for the app to be removed from the App Store.